# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать так, чтобы сайт запущенный на Denwer был доступен на всех устройствах локальной сети?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно протестировать сайт на мобильном устройстве.

Comment: А разве из коробки он не доступен на всех устройствах?

Comment: Вот тут почитай [faq](http://www.denwer.ru/faq/shared.html)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо или вместе с денвером [Browsersync](https://browsersync.io).  Он очень хорошо решает вашу задачу.